# Name of a monastery/restaurant in Austria

Tags: switzerland, identify-this, restaurants, austria

About 3 years ago, I hiked through this village in Austria near its borders with Switzerland and Germany. Unfortunately, neither my friend or I can remember the name of the village. We also ate at a restaurant (had schnitzel) that had been converted from a monastery that overlooked the village. Can anyone help me remember the name of the village or the monastery/restaurant?

[image]

Comment: You don't happen to have any picture of the place? How about a faint memory of its approximate geographical location? Just trying to narrow this down.

Comment: Is it the Burgrestaurant Gebhardsberg in Bregenz? http://www.greber.cc/fileadmin/dam/_LAYOUT/banner_ghbg_home.png

Comment: Could be. Attached is a pic of the view

Comment: @Kaleb that looks like Feldkirch. Could't say what the monastery/restaurant was though, so I'll leave this as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Ah ok, then I know what it is. Schattenburg!

Comment: This one? https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schattenburg

Comment: yes that is the one!

Comment: @RoflcoptrException Thanks for the cookie. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Google reverse image search](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZivDzWwoJ6D89o0IhZAL6y8QheAbBXBBEPZBBpeXuItD-JxljvTPMbW18mKCH_1Z0HJn-OYzy-8xK5E-APQrqZ7xSjBWwjBbgCHtM2JnJae2i3fKdckiLjQSS7VcRDnTG1ur4rEu2RSn7iz3IxolKUQsMOi672r9N-cNWnzQbOnHjNhZHNzONuFy0b96p7oLZqFGuePpFZVwV2GcM1QwcWwWT04djRGoQr37bzO75V_1Qbwcu8Tq4w61TiiaOGLJ7XJCfF5bUPtPQklEs7PquDfiLXcBQuOWdPKPShsaW3Z6vpeJT7j3JDshnrAaG3srudujMS5389FC3zcVfTwPWr-ctbyQQuLGTqmTim6nJahv86Rx6KUgHNxyKo3mipx0ZBlFlB0V0jvG8dX9uFeEXBRrJfOowbkaHG0EBJELSMlZw7Xz-khxQwWQSMtzywmd2nW9Ownj7uVdnPQet6XP5zM7AKs17GkRjM7mPasRp_1eGB1LQfF-VaU8Rpib1RH0fuqXbXCHPvAiwL29G4YeO1zBgHUTrg2y6vEwtJRbIX7zSSfjWBRH3aR08i2X0STKg9JCLD8OZ-UsuSrYWp_1CXaheCjPRIn3QCAckFSWhJ-DZcVyZWgBEQAcg30wUorBJdYs2ZH3Fhl0lHoph7JFzqPHq1tIC_199BrE-vtsCCrcrnLnHvERiYvX3PKOP2fkHxTYlhzvCaR4AEyaqOwjqkFcEVA8JFGflldppg9HKeQuV4J_1l3yom3vEA4KUxC_1jpGOl2H1e922JwkEOA02GJi4n3akLzhABUkAfK8dUoOaRjpfXqOjEb0YiRVP0hM5XoX5M1IO2TDiIrH75FsLKGPcHd-IbJ0H7juOvpkIA0hcFUjA-ku-3uOqIwPMeYXV9hqGIXajepXKZ-I4Od0hZHicEUuwhGZ-YrREoM_1qNTRt6THrkPnIfVwlC-udcYHQwLxrExgjhHlc6iGxdC_1nxqmm1Lc-MHH5aQk65V8igwQtD07WatL508jhukHInpD7duI_1QygylcoCN0ehtQY02GbedjCFL2ejECh-TbovJYqkFqi3YtE3sxbrvEKgUCZnKVgmcDNQr-im1H8I54GJio1bEiY0knMxJJX2ner2-ri0_1i929-XMPUHeWJWT4j2od6RgTYveP46-79yubO9GBLCRjrpXDQgIJkpwDDvf4525foZztpQulBi5N-e2ulUK53lX6aDHkmY5xNdjOa7YD5SmA4e5D0TtbFZfoZboXyUq9g_1zx92eJDbKyo33EsDoqR1r_1R9d1reAjWpfyQsctAivnv9D2SmlDN9Xu87u5GBb1uvZJ83SZZmU31oMm5MOzgYKr3xvm-8n9GFsxauKmEIbEG8IgttjZpv5Ug0XJO83qwx65ao1F2zkhBwTEIBKpbKvZAtHsRvCe3PJZJS5ccU1LTKL4sxiTyMC0LVkIH4vjkDOgGXE9z2M7A1q8cUEAyPRd9QSS20Eo3HZuUFnByIbQAs6Gs-j4vu_1lVYNoElt69Jh0kkDt7LPmd_1TdlVfNHYiqfkn3KX5CEM-TmSbsjeRmXf9v0ooAV63YGkHJI_1OVIDtD2qxm2QM6nAijXqh-ewfY-RtBv_13FtmFxBIElD6YVntKNCxp6FXFrBztddAh9CeNsbjyt9TKM&hl=en) says that it might be [Feldkirch, Vorarlberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feldkirch,_Vorarlberg). Indeed the church and the first house in the foreground (the one with the two windows underneath the straight part of the roof) seem to be the ones in the picture below from Wikipedia:

[image: Feldkirch, Vorarlberg] 
<sup>[File:Feldkirch3.jpg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Feldkirch3.jpg), Wikimedia Commons, CC by SA 3.0</sup>

[Google maps places it here.](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Feldkirch,+Austria/@47.2521096,9.5468057,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x479b3bd82eb275cf:0xf91dbdbc8db78df0)

[By precise triangulation, arcane magic and top-secred heuristics](https://goo.gl/maps/c5sWaC88sUL2) I'd say that the place you ate was the [Schlosswirtschaft Shattenburg](http://www.schattenburg.at/):

[image: Shattenburg]
<sup>[Schattenburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schattenburg#/media/File:SchattenburgFK14.JPG), Wikimedia Commons, CC by SA 2.5</sup>

Comment: yes that must be it meaning the restaurant was a castle not a monastery - http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurant_Review-g190450-d1319582-Reviews-Schlosswirtschaft_Schattenburg-Feldkirch_Vorarlberg_Austrian_Alps.html

Comment: Yes, and it's not close to the German border. It's close to the Liechtenstein border.

Comment: Memory was a bit hazy on that but yes near the Liechtenstein border

Answer (score 11):

It's feldkirch.  I live near there.

(It's the view from the schattenburg, the blue "hypo" sign in both pictures is the same sign)